# How to divide a SWF file?

Tags: split, flash

Is it possible to divide a SWF file into n parts? (for example n = 2)

what i mean is not division in time, but division in space. i want to have 2 swf files for example, one is left half of master swf and other is right half. is that possible?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you know: `swf` is generally pronounced `swiff`. `swc` is generally pronounced `swick`. Noticed the `an` in your title and my guess is that you pronounce it S-W-F. They'll catch that on an interview.

Comment: i didn't know, thank you for information :) yes, i was pronuncing it as s - w - f :)

Comment: No, you can't split an existing swf in two, like for example you can do with a PNG image, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. One note though: two physically distinct .swf's one next to each other is probably a bad idea. One master .swf into which two .swf's are loaded could work, depending on your needs.

Please consult this:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14190.html

it has all the ways that one can use to position files in as2 and as3.

Generally, you are going to have one low size master file, and two much bigger .swfs that will be loaded inside it.

Some things to note: depending on your application and whether you are using as3 or as2, it might be prefered to simply load images and other data into .swf's instead of doing this.

Also, you can actually start to load a .swf, lets say an animation before the whole .swf has actually downloaded.

So it will load 5% of the whole file and start the animation. If the download slows down, the .swf animation will stall, but it will continue as soon as more data is downloaded or the speed picks up. The same can be done for any programmed .swf, though it requries a few tricks and a little bit of programming. Ask another question if you are interested in this last thing.

Comment: you said "Yes, it is possible." but how? what i need is exactly two physically distinct swf files, one master swf which loads 2 other does not solve my problem. btw, i have flash itself and i can generate my swf myself, is it possible to generate it that way rather than splitting one that already exists?

Comment: sorry, my intended message got lost during my edits. No, splitting a single .swf into two and maintaining automatic connectivity between them is not possible. One could manually make connect them via javascript and ExternallInterface to ferry data back and forth between them but compared to a master swf loading two other it's a worse idea... If you want more info ask...

Comment: i will somehow synchronize them myself. but if it is impossible to split one swf into two, then i will have to do something else. maybe using flash itself (flash professional or sth), i can generate 2 swf files while exporting? is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to take a single swf file and divide it into multiple swf binaries.

What you could do is build a shell swf that loads the child swf n times, and presents them each with custom masks. However, you would effectively be running multiple instances of the child swf, so performance overhead would multiply.